# ShareKit twitter 403 (unknown error)

Tags: ios, twitter, sharekit

I'm using ShareKit to share through FB and twitter. I'm using this code to share to twitter:

```
- (IBAction)twitterShare:(id)sender {
    // Create the item to share (in this example, a url)
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[flexViewController shareURL]];
    SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:[flexViewController shareText]];

    [SHK setRootViewController:self];
    // Share the item
    [SHKTwitter shareItem:item];
}
```

I'm getting "403 Forbidden:The server understood the request but is refusing to fulfill it". This always happens if the login view was prompted. If the user was already logged in from an earlier session (the app was closed and reopened), it works correctly.

In this page, it declares that 403 means I have reached a limit, which I don't think it's my case.
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses

The above code worked correctly last week, but now I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ran into the same issue using the old version of ShareKit and was able to solve by editing the Twitter URL in the following section of SHKTwitter.m.

```
    - (void)sendStatus
{
    OAMutableURLRequest *oRequest = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"]
```

The URL was different in the ShareKit 2.0 version.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and worked, but I already switched to a different toolkit.